# Trying to set an Listener which is abstracted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, listener, motion

I'm working right now on an little app to test arround with motion and touch events. I am facing the problem that my Listener class has to be abstracted but I cannot create an object from that listener which I would need to put it on the "setOnTouchListener" method of an imageView.

Listener class:

```
abstract class GestureListener(directionDisplayer: TextView) : View.OnTouchListener,` GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    private var directionDisplayer: TextView = directionDisplayer

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this)
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        return true
    }

    override fun onFling(
        downEvent: MotionEvent?,
        moveEvent: MotionEvent?,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        var result = false

        if (downEvent != null && moveEvent != null) {
            var diffY: Float = moveEvent.y - downEvent.y
            var diffX: Float = moveEvent.x - downEvent.x

            val SWIPE_MIN = 100
            val SWIPE_Velocity = 100 //TODO WIDTH

            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                //RIGHT OR LEFT
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_MIN && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_Velocity) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        swipeRight()
                    } else {
                        swipeLeft()
                    }
                    result = true
                }
            } else {
                //UP OR DOWN
                if(Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_MIN && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_Velocity) {
                    if(diffY > 0) {
                        swipeUp()
                    } else {
                        swipeDown()
                    }
                    result = true
                }


            }

        }
        return result
    }

    private fun swipeDown() {
        directionDisplayer.text = "Direction: DOWN"
    }

    private fun swipeUp() {
        directionDisplayer.text = "Direction: UP"
    }

    private fun swipeLeft() {
        directionDisplayer.text = "Direction: LEFT"
    }

    private fun swipeRight() {
        directionDisplayer.text = "Direction: RIGHT"
    }

MainActivity (only the important):

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val canvasImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.canvas)

        canvasImage.setOnTouchListener(GestureListener(findViewById(R.id.showDirection)))
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: If it has to be abstract that you have to pass object that implements GestureListener in your canvasImage.setOnTouchListener line

Comment: Do you mean like this? "object:GestureListener(...)"

Comment: Yes, just like this, and you can do object:GestureListener(){//there you can override methods}

Comment: Well it's a bit different in Kotlin so I think it should be fine also to help people that have their first programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GestureListener` is an abstract class. So, you have to implement the members of `iew.OnTouchListener` and `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` not yet implemented either in the abstract class itself or in your code like this-

```
    canvasImage.setOnTouchListener(object : GestureListener(textView) {
        override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun onScroll(
            e1: MotionEvent?,
            e2: MotionEvent?,
            distanceX: Float,
            distanceY: Float
        ): Boolean {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpfull answer already. Just got a little bit confused... as you can see I wanted to check if a person swiped up, right, left, down in my listener. But now these implemented methods are only triggered and idk if I used now the right events at all in my listener class or how to connect my self made code from my listener into these implemented events